ValueError: Protocol message OcrConfig has no "premium_features" field when use DocumentAI
I'm using Font-style detection in Google's DocumentAI using Python:
"premium_features": {
                "compute_style_info": True
                },

But it gives the following error:
ValueError: Protocol message OcrConfig has no "premium_features" field.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/enterprise-document-ocr#font-style_detection
p.s. I run the Python code in the Terminal after setting up the gcloud environment using gcloud auth login

It turns out the client library is outdated. So I did the following.
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-documentai
And it solved it.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries#install
